# RCurl httpPOST JSON

Tags: r, rscript, rserve

Hi I'm trying to write a script using R where I post data to a specific weblink and get the response back. I'm not really sure how to set curl headers for Content-type and Application.

this is what I have so far:

```
library("RCurl")
httpPOST("http://localhost", '{"title":"ello World!"}')
```

I get the following error:
Error in curlOptions(..., .opts = .opts) : unnamed curl option(s):
....

If use curl from command line the data does get posted.

Is there another library in R that does CURL and JSON posts better?

Comment: I think it's easier to call `curlPerform` directly because it's more intuitive., or look into the **httr** package. In `httpPOST`, you have to name all of the arguments (which need to be curl arguments, see `listCurlOptions()`), one of which is called `httpheader` and can contain the fields you're trying to send.

Comment: I kinda got it to work with curlPerform, just having some issues with getting JSON from file and uploading it using curlPerform. I'm sure it won't be that bad. Thanks for helping out @Thomas.

Comment: Feel free to update your question if you're still stuck on something and I can take a look.